spring batch unit testing - jobExecution can't be null error
I'm using spring boot starter batch 3.3.3 and spring batch test 5.1.2.  Trying to unit test a step of a flow job with a bunch of steps. I get the error that jobExecution can't be null -- unfortunately, I don't see any spring batch 5.x.x launchStep unit test examples out there, but from what I see, I think I'm doing the usual stuff.
I'm using autowired jobLauncherTestUtils --
    JobExecution jobExecution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createJobExecution();
    jobRepository.update(jobExecution);  // experimented with this but no change
    jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    ExecutionContext executionContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();

    jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(batchRequestJob);
    JobExecution result = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(
      "step-1-create",
      Job.jobParameters()
    );

error is
jobExecution must not be null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jobExecution must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:172)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:286)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:59)
    at org.springframework.batch.test.StepRunner.launchJob(StepRunner.java:175)
    at org.springframework.batch.test.StepRunner.launchStep(StepRunner.java:165)
    at org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:241)
    at org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:214)
    at points.pie.core.configuration.TestBatchJobConfiguration.requestJobCreateStep(TestBatchJobConfiguration.java:225)
...
...
...


Interesting! I don't see why this fails with an IAE. Can you please share a complete junit test or open an issue on Github with a failing test? I will take a look asap. Thank you upfront.

Thanks Mahmoud - I created a github issue but have since closed it - I was able to take elements from the Juni4 test and make my code work! Cheers! https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/test/SpringBatchTestJUnit4Tests.java

Oh great to hear that, glad you solved your issue! It would be great to add an answer with how you solved your issue. This could help others in the same situation. Best regards.
